# coreos dex compile error

Tags: coreos

I am trying to complete the coreos dex //github.com/coreos/dex.git. I have cloned and installed the dependency packages in Centos & with Go version 1.9.

When I run make its throwing below error message.

```
 git clone https://github.com/coreos/dex.git
 cd dex
 make

# make
can't load package: package github.com/coreos/dex/cmd/dex: cannot find package "github.com/coreos/dex/cmd/dex" in any of:
        /usr/lib/golang/src/github.com/coreos/dex/cmd/dex (from $GOROOT)
        /root/work/src/github.com/coreos/dex/cmd/dex (from $GOPATH)
make: *** [bin/dex] Error 1
```

using glide installed all the required dependency packages.

```
[INFO]  Exporting resolved dependencies...
[INFO]  --> Exporting github.com/beevik/etree
[INFO]  --> Exporting github.com/coreos/etcd
[INFO]  --> Exporting github.com/ghodss/yaml
[INFO]  --> Exporting github.com/coreos/go-oidc
[INFO]  --> Exporting github.com/golang/protobuf
[INFO]  --> Exporting github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach-go
[INFO]  --> Exporting github.com/gtank/cryptopasta
[INFO]  --> Exporting github.com/inconshreveable/mousetrap
[INFO]  --> Exporting github.com/jonboulle/clockwork
[INFO]  --> Exporting github.com/spf13/cobra
[INFO]  --> Exporting github.com/kylelemons/godebug
[INFO]  --> Exporting github.com/pquerna/cachecontrol
[INFO]  --> Exporting github.com/russellhaering/goxmldsig
[INFO]  --> Exporting github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3
[INFO]  --> Exporting github.com/sirupsen/logrus
[INFO]  --> Exporting github.com/gorilla/context
[INFO]  --> Exporting github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
[INFO]  --> Exporting github.com/gorilla/handlers
[INFO]  --> Exporting github.com/gorilla/mux
[INFO]  --> Exporting github.com/lib/pq
[INFO]  --> Exporting github.com/spf13/pflag
[INFO]  --> Exporting golang.org/x/crypto
[INFO]  --> Exporting golang.org/x/net
[INFO]  --> Exporting google.golang.org/genproto
[INFO]  --> Exporting google.golang.org/appengine
[INFO]  --> Exporting golang.org/x/oauth2
[INFO]  --> Exporting golang.org/x/sys
[INFO]  --> Exporting gopkg.in/asn1-ber.v1
[INFO]  --> Exporting gopkg.in/ldap.v2
[INFO]  --> Exporting google.golang.org/grpc
[INFO]  --> Exporting golang.org/x/text
[INFO]  --> Exporting gopkg.in/yaml.v2
[INFO]  --> Exporting gopkg.in/square/go-jose.v2
[INFO]  Replacing existing vendor dependencies
```

Any tips to resolve this compile issue?

Answer (score 0):

found the right steps to build the dex from here https://github.com/coreos/dex/blob/master/Documentation/getting-started.md

```
$ go get github.com/coreos/dex
$ cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/coreos/dex
$ make
```